# How to write a good mock for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I code in Python and I'm starting to use the [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) library.

Although I've read through all of the documentation, something that I'm finding hard to understand is 'What makes a good mock'.

For example, say I've got a function that makes a HTTP request:

```
def fetch_url(url, method=urlfetch.GET, data=''):
    """Send a HTTP request"""

    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method=method, payload=data,
                            headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})

    return result.content
```

What would a good mock for this function look like? Furthermore, what would then be tested?

From my understanding, the characteristics of a good test are that the test checks:

1. That the code isn't broken
2. That the code acts as expected
3. That the code returns the expected output if it returns something

That said, what would be the characteristics of a good mock?

Comment: I have never done mocking using the mock however I have used mox. Also in you above function fetch_url you cant really mock anything, because  urlfetch.fetch is the only thing that is giving the result that has to be checked against the expected result. moreover you are passing the required arguments  such as url, method and data at the function fetch_url being called.  You only mock what you do not need to audit the behaviour when in that case you can also do monkeypatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good mock:

1. acts as a stand-in for an object dependency of the unit under test.
2. provides meaningful "fake" behavior for that object dependency.
3. Isolates the unit under test from the real dependency (which has its own tests).

Not very exciting, is it?

The very best mocks are the ones that write themselves, with the help of a mocking library like Moq or Rhino Mocks.  The documentation for these libraries gives a pretty good overview of how, when and where to best use mocks.